# VBA function to copy and paste data from a workbook,based on a set of conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The task at hand:
I have 2 tables: one that needs to be filled with the data from the mastersheet and the mastersheet. Examples below:

[image]
[image]

I need to copy the data from the green sheet and, based on the date and specific text on line and column, to paste it into the white sheet in the correct columns and skip the incorrect ones. the delta line just calculates the differences between the mastersheet and evidence cells.

Until now i tried multiple formulas such as vlookup after the date in the white, but it grabs just the numbers from method 1, and if i use something like =if(and(A2=":\green.xlsx[sheet1]"A2; b2="mastersheet"; C1="method1"), ":\green.xlsx[sheet1]"C2; " "), and vlookups that grabs only the data for the method1 (but it does it correctly)

Tried to write a macro in vba and here is one of the problems: it returns runtime error 52. Code below:

```vb
Sub GrabFillData()
'declaring variables and explaining each one role
Dim path As String
Dim newfo As Workbook 'newfo is the newly opened workbook
Dim newfows As Sheets 'newfows is a speciffied sheet to copy data from



With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

If path <> "" Then
    Open path For Output As #n      ' runtime error 52
End If
```

The same error i get when i use

```vb
Sub GetPath()
Dim path As String

path = InputBox("Enter a file path", "Title Here")
Open path For Output As #1
Close #1
End Sub
```

Another problem is that i thought i knew how to make the conditions for the copy-paste actions and i need a little help with that.

The macro will be running from the white sheet.

If there any formula that can make this easier?

Comment: It is only clear where and where from to handle data. Please, explain **in words** what exactly is to be copied and based on which logic/algorithm.

Comment: the logic is as follows: Let's take, for example, the first date from column1. If the dates from white and green match, payment1 is the same as method1 and the cell in white corresponds with mastersheet, take the sums/numbers from green and paste it in the cells on the mastersheet line and in the payment column, accordingly. The script will do this for each date, until the table is empty or until there are no more matches between data. I really can't explain this better. This is task i'm doing manually, by the same rules. Also, the script will run from the white sheet.

Comment: Two more issues to be clarified: 1. Is it possible to find more than one occurrence for each  method? I mean, is it possible to have 'method1` = 26.39 and on other row a new value? You said "sums/numbers"... 2. Are there enough data filled in the white sheet template for all cases in white and green sheet?

Comment: Should the maximum number of methods be 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code to process the two sheets as (I understood) you need. You did not answer my last clarification questions and the code assumes that maximum number of methods is 4 and unique occurrences exist for each such method. Using arrays and working mostly in memory, the code should be very fast, even for large ranges. It will return in "H2" all processed range. If you like the return, you should replace "H2" with "A2" in the last code line:

```
Sub ProcessPayments()
 Dim shT As Worksheet, lastRT As Long, shM As Worksheet, lastRM As Long, dict As Object
 Dim arr, arrInt, arrT, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, arrMeth, mtch
 arrMeth = Split("method1,method2,method3,method4", ",")

 Set shT = ActiveSheet 'the white sheet
 lastRT = shT.Range("A" & shT.rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row in A:A
 arrT = shT.Range("A2:F" & lastRT).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration

 Set shM = shT.Next ' use here the master sheet you need
 lastRM = shM.Range("A" & shM.rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row in A:A
 arr = shM.Range("A2:C" & lastRM).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration

 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)    'iterate between the array rows and place the necessary values in dictionary
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'when the dictionary key does not exist, add a dictionary key as the Date value:
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))) 'place the item as an array of two elements (method and value)
    Else                     'if the key exists, it add another element in the jagged array containing method ad value
        arrInt = dict(arr(i, 1)): ReDim Preserve arrInt(UBound(arrInt) + 1)  'redim the existing array item with one element
        arrInt(UBound(arrInt)) = Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))                 'place another array of two in the last added element
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrInt                                                             'place the intermediary array back to dictionary
    End If
 Next i

 'Put the necessary data in the white sheet fields:
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)                      'iterate between the array elements:
    If arrT(i, 2) = "mastersheet" Then          'for the rows having "mastersheet" in the second column:
        For j = 0 To dict.count - 1             'iterate between the dictionary keys:
            If arrT(i, 1) = dict.Keys()(j) Then 'when the dictionary key has been found:
                For k = 0 To UBound(dict.items()(j)) 'Iterate between each array of the jag array item:
                    'match the array first item (method) in arrMeth (to set the column where to place the value):
                    mtch = Application.match(dict.items()(j)(k)(0), arrMeth, 0)
                    arrT(i, mtch + 2) = dict.items()(j)(k)(1)   'place the value in the appropriate column (the second array element)
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    End If
 Next i
 'Place back the processed array, but not in "A2", only to check if its return is convenient and drop its content in "H2".
 'If convenient, please replace "H2" whith "A2"
shT.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrT), UBound(arrT, 2)).value = arrT
End Sub
```

I could not understand from your question if the two involved sheets belong to the same workbook. The above code works with sheets from different workbooks/worksheets, too. You should take care to correctly set `shM`. Now it is the next sheet after the white one...

If you need to let the code opening the workbook using a dialog, this should be piece of cake. You already received answer(s) for this simple parte, I think...

I tried commenting each code line. If something not so clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. But after testing it...

Comment: first, thank you very much! Second, i've ran some tests and i found that, if i replace H2 with A2 and run the script, it comes out as blank. The same without the replacement. Basically, the values are stores someway, but not displayed in the table. Question: in the line ```arrMeth = Split("method1,method2,method3,method4", ",")``` the methods needs to be the same across all workbooks, right?

Comment: @NoobQuestions1 A2 should replace H2 **only if you see it working as you want**. 1. What sheet did you set as `shM`? What does it contain? Is there a table **starting from "A1"**? It cannot be seen in the picture you posted 2. Are there a range starting from **A2 to F column**, as in the picture you show? If nothing in A:A, no range can be built. 3. The array `arrMeth` is built once and used in all the code to determine the column where the found `method' has been found. Can you share the workbook you test, or a dummy one? Then, if you answer once per day, this process will take for ever...

Comment: I figured it out at the end. Thanks for the code bit. I'll try to deconstruct/debug it and reuse it (or make it work) in a further development plan. Sorry for not answering as fast as i needed to. I know it's for my own sake.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the column names in white sheet to "method1", "method2",...
OR
If you can change the row values in green sheet to "payment1", "payment2",...
Then you can use a complex INDEX MATCH function.
Follow the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxACM.png

Using VBA there are a couple of thing with your code.. let's go 1 by 1.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, path As String

'You can use FileDialogFilePicker instead
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False    'Forces to choose 1 file.
    If .Show = -1 Then    'Checks if OK button was clicked.
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

'Use Workbooks.Open method instead of Open.
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

Copy Pasting is easy.

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste from A1 to B5
```

Comment: The open method cleared the error. I'll tinker with the index match function and see what i can do. Question: the match between indexes needs to be exact, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GrabFillData()
'declaring variables and explaining each one role
Dim path As String
Dim newfo As Excel.Workbook 'newfo is the newly opened workbook
Dim Cell_1 As String  ' Cell_1 refer to one cell in workbook
Dim newfows As Integer 'newfows is a speciffied sheet to copy data from
newfows = ActiveSheet.Index


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

If path <> "" Then
    'Open path For Output As #n      ' runtime error 52
  Set newfo = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(path) ' connect to workbook
  Cell_1 = newfo.Sheets(newfows).Cells(2, 2) ' retrieve value of selected cell to string variable
End If

End Sub
```